# Spring-Data JPA Repository with MongoDB how to findAll elements using distinct with multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, distinct-values

I have an application with SpringData which uses Repositories(interfaces) to perform queries to MongoDB.

I was wondering how can I perform a `findAll` instruction using `distinct` with two values, i.e.:

Collection: people

columns: name, lastName, address

Find all different users(name & lastName).

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB `distinct` allows to retrieve distinct values of a single field across a collection, which is different to other stores. You can find more about `distinct` in the MongoDB reference [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

In order retrieve multi field distinct values you need to use a `$group` [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#retrieve-distinct-values) that you can then apply via the `@Aggregation`.

Might look something like this:

```
{ '$group': 
    { 
        '_id' : { '$concat' : ['$lastname', '$firstname'] },
        'lastname' : { '$first' : '$lastname' },
        'firstname' : { '$first' : '$firstname' }
    } 
}
```

```java
@Aggregation("{ '$group' : { '_id' : { '$concat' : ...
List<Person> findAllDistinctFirstnameLastname();
```